# Android theme doesn't work on API < 22 (Android 5.0 Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to use theme in my app.
I want to override style of `EditText` globally, but this doesn't work on API < 22 (Android 5.0 Lollipop)

Here is my theme declaration

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextDefault</item>
</style>
```

Declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".application.MyApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

My `EditText` custom style

```
<style name="EditTextDefault" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_blue</item>
</style>
```

And I in xml files it should work without specifying `@style` attribute explicitly. But it doesn't work on API < 22.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_text_password"
    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_login"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

In order to make it work on any version of API I have to specify style attribute

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_text_password"
    android:hint="@string/hint_enter_login"
    style="@style/EditTextDefault"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

I have tried to find info about this, but there is nowhere stated that theme will not work on api < 22.